# Pls help , in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array

Tags: php

How to resolve this error:

> Warning: `in_array()` expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in `/web/htdocs/website/home/wp-content/plugins/powerpack-elements/classes/class-pp-helper.php` on line 198

```
$saved_widgets = pp_get_enabled_modules();

if ( is_array( $widgets ) ) {

    foreach ( $widgets as $slug => $data ) {

        if ( in_array( $data['name'], $saved_widgets, true ) ) { //  ( line 198)
            $widgets[ $slug ]['is_activate'] = true;
        } else {
            $widgets[ $slug ]['is_activate'] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like `pp_get_enabled_modules()` returns a string, not an array.

Comment: The error is pretty clear on both the issue and the solution. Do a `var_dump($saved_widgets);` and see what it actually contains.

Comment: I suspect you're just looking for support for a third-party WordPress plugin. If that's the case, you should tag the question accordingly and add a link to the plugin site.